# In Excel 2013, where are Visual Basic (VBA), Macros and AddIn tools?

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel 2013, where are options and tools such as Visual Basic (VBA), Macros and AddIn tools? Are they supported?

Comment: See the canonical Super User question: [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](http://superuser.com/q/801609/354511)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By default, Excel 2013 doesn't show developer tools.

They can be enabled by selecting *File → Options → Customize Ribbon*.

In the *Customize the Ribbon* (Main Tabs) window pane, scroll down to the *Developer* option and check it. Now Excel will display a ribbon tab named *Developer*.

Comment: "By default, Excel 2013 doesn't show developer tools." - Neither do Word/Excel etc. from the 2007 version onwards, ever since the ribbon was introduced. The **View** tab though does have a **Macros** button/menu.

Comment: quick access, if you only want it on an occasional basis, can be done through ALT+F11